# how to check that how much page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I am trying to make a progress bar through java script library `progress.js` and i want to show that how much page has been. I want to do this through my progress bar. How can i check that how much page has been loaded?

Comment: The browser already does that.

Comment: but i want to show this through the progress bar how can i do this. Any simple way?

Comment: It depends what you're loading.

Comment: i wan to apply on my login page that when user login correctly then the progress bar will show that how much page has been loaded

Answer (score 1):

May be your need to try by calculating response header size and then calculate `%`

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', document.location, false);
request.send();
var size = request.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase().match(/content-length: \d+/);
alert(size);
```

You will get size in bytes.